# Why is there no option to set a java project on eclipse to Apache Derby nature?

Tags: eclipse, derby

I copied the tree folders of the plugin and added them to eclipse -> plugins, but there is still no option to add derby nature. Im using derby 10.8.1. Can some help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The Apache Derby Eclipse plug-ins are extremely old and use a plugin.xml format that is no longer supported. They will not work in current Eclipse releases.

10.8 is very old, current Apache Derby releases no longer provide any Eclipse plug-ins.

Comment: Ok thank you. Which database software do you recommend if I want to create my own tables and access to their data through eclipse?

Comment: You can still use Derby, the old plug-ins didn't do very much. Eclipse DTP (Data Tools Platform) provides lots of stuff for any database system.